# Dedupe array on basis of two things

Tags: java, java-stream

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Dedupe {
    public static class Pro {
        String name;
        Long firstPresent;

        public RouteHijack(String name, Long firstPresent, String matchedPrefix) {
            this.name = name;
            this.firstPresent = firstPresent;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Pro> pros = new ArrayList<>();
        pros.add(new Pro("John", (long) 3));
        pros.add(new Pro("Umar", (long) 1));
        pros.add(new Pro("John", (long) 2));
        pros.add(new Pro("John", (long) 0));
    }
}
```

Hi,
I want to dedupe the above array on basis of [name + Smallest value of firstPresent]. The desired resultant arry should contain
`[Pro<"John", 0>, <"Umar", 1>]`

I am looking forward some simpler way using language feature like stream or something similar. Do you know any simple way to achieve this in java8? Thanks for the help.

p.s: One solution is as below

```
Map<String, String> prosMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Pro pro : pros) {
  String name = pro.getName();
  Long firstPresent = pro.getFirstPresent();
  String data =  prosMap.getOrDefault(name, 0);
  if (data < firstPresent) {
    prosMap.put(name, firstPresent);
  }
}
// Change the Map to array.
```

Comment: "*While I know few ways to achieve the goal...*" - Please share at least one of those ways.

Comment: If you know how to do it, then why do you need us to help? Have you done any research? It's highly unlikely anyone will answer your question without this.

Comment: "*Do you know any simple way*" - Simpler than what? Please share some code that solves the problem.

Comment: One solution is to iterate over the array like below
for (Pro pros : pros) {}

Comment: @TahirRauf this would not even compile due to a name clash. Also, this is only a `foreach` loop and not enough to fulfill the requriement given in the post.

Comment: I am sorry, I pressed the enter too soon. 
One solution is to iterate over the array like below
```
Map<String, String> prosMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Pro pro : pros) {
  String name = pro.getName();
  Long firstPresent = pro.getFirstPresent();
  String data =  prosMap.getOrDefault(name, 0);
  if (data < firstPresent) {
    prosMap.put(name, firstPresent);
  }
}

// Change the Map to array.```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add the code. Also, please include the full code (including the conversion of the `Map` to an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wonderful `toMap` collector in Java 8 stream API:

```java
pros.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(pro -> pro.name, pro -> pro,
                (a, b) -> a.firstPresent > b.firstPresent ? b : a
))
```

The third argument is a `BinaryOperator` merge function that takes two `Pro` objects and returns only one of them.

After collecting to a map you can simply call `values()` to get `Collection<Pro>`

Comment: Thanks alot. That was precisely what I was looking for. I really appreciate your help.